# Customize page bar in Power BI Report Server

Tags: customization, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, reportserver

Is there any way to customize (change color etc.) the Power BI page bar in Power BI Report Server?

[image]

Comment: It's not customizable other than changing the page name.

Comment: Too bad, thanks anyways!